# How to secure the connection php file?

Tags: php

Hello I have a php file where I make a connection to the database.

Conexion_file.php

```
<?php  
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxx','xxxx','xxxx');
?>
```

and in my main file I require that file:

mainfile.php

```
<?php 
require('conexion_file.php'); 
//code..
?>
```

This is my question, what should be the name of the connection file? or Can I use another extension for this file? so I can make a little bit harder some one can get the information from this file.
Thanks.

Comment: Secure from what? Browsing via a URL? FTP? SSH?

Comment: sorry about that, I suppose there was a way to retrieve the content of the php file and some one can get the name of my connection file and do something that I don't know with that information.

Comment: if they have access to your system, then it doesn't matter where you put it.

Comment: I'm not trying to defend my question, it is a dumb assumption, but thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your connection file doesn't echo the connection settings - you're fine.. Omit the closing `?>` PHP tag, too.

If you're really concerned, you can move the config file outside of the public-facing web root. As long as PHP has access outside of its own directory, you can use absolute paths to include the config file.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do not echo or print the data out, nobody will be able to see this info (as long it' s getting interpretet).

However your best bet is to put **outside** of your public accessable web-root. In many cases this one layer above your `public_html` directory.

You can also secure your files with a `.htaccess` file and deny access to this file (don' t worry your scripts will still be able to include it!).